# date function for php

Tags: php, date, datestamp

Would the date function for php recognize this code, and convert it to a Date Stamp

```
$date= date('$_POST["Month1"]/$_POST["Date1"]/$_POST["Year1"]');
```

?

Comment: No, because of [single quotes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php).

Comment: please show var_dump($_POST);

Comment: PHP handles variables inside [single quotes](http://us1.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single) as plain strings, not as variables.

Comment: and the format? take a look at the documentation http://es1.php.net/manual/es/function.date.php

Comment: @aleation - oh, man, I didn't even notice that it was the wrong function. driving with blinders, gets me every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is unclear and not works because of single quotes. Better try with:

```
$date = date($_POST["Month1"] . '/' . $_POST["Date1"] . '/' . $_POST["Year1"]);
```

If your post data contains format, like `m`, `d`, `Y` - it's ok. But if you pass date like `4`, `21`, `2014` - `date()` will not work. Convert it to timestamp with:

```
$timestamp = strtotime($_POST["Month1"] . '/' . $_POST["Date1"] . '/' . $_POST["Year1"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is wrong, as already stated, but it's also better for avoiding formatting issues to actually just pass in the variables individually to [`mktime()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php), like this:

```
$timestamp = mktime(0, 0, 0, $_POST["Month1"], $_POST["Date1"], $_POST["Year1"]);
```

That way you aren't having to pass the variables you already have broken up through any extra steps.